# finding the centre of dynamically generated divs

Tags: jquery

I have a page that contain n amount of divs in columns of 3. The divs are potentially different widths, and some divs will contain one image, whereas some will contain two. Image number one is always centred in the div. Unfortunately, the way the page is generated it's impossible to have image number 2 sit a certain and consistent distance from image number one - which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Each image number 2 has a unique asp.net client Id followed by icon e.g. ctl00_icon.

Each image one has the same name - not my doing!

Non of the divs have an id

So what I thought about doing was - get the width of each div, divide it my 2, and use this to give my image 2 a reference point for positioning.

Any pointers on how I might go about achieving this? Or is there a better way?
Thanks
Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some way to identify the divs to get the width. Try one of the following two ways:

By parent element:

```
$('div.parent').children('div').eq(1).width(); // this is the second child div
```

By unique child:

```
$('img[src*=unique_id]').closest('div').width();
```

You can then use that width in your calculations for image positioning.

Comment: Thanks for you response. If there are multiple divs would I not need to use something like the each method to iterate through them?

Comment: Yes, I misread your post. Do something like: `$('div.parent').children('div').each( function() { this.width()...})`